# Highlight mouse cursor when clicking

Tags: windows, gratis, presentation

I am looking for a tool that highlights the mouse cursor when clicking.

It should

- be gratis, open source preferred
- run on Windows 7 to 10

Ideally

- color is configurable
- it has different colors or shapes for single click and double click

I found a commercial tool [PointerFocus](http://www.pointerfocus.com/index.html) which looks much like what I want. There's a [similar question for OSX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/highlight-mouse-position-on-os-x)

Comment: Even if Win7 is obsolete, I am still interested for a solution for this OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1782155/mouse-clicks-during-windows-10-screen-recording), PowerToys (free and open-source) has a [Mouse highlighter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/mouse-utilities#mouse-highlighter) feature.

[image]

It is available only for Windows 10 (and not 7) though.

Note: those click highlights aren't recorded when using Windows 10 Screen recording, see this [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1782155/mouse-clicks-during-windows-10-screen-recording#comment2783327_1782155), so we have to use another software for screen recording, such as ShareX.

Comment: I can accept PowerToys now, since my Windows 7 requirement from 2016 can be dropped,.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm still interested in a Windows 7 solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try realcursoreditor

http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-maker

Then i used this profile:

http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-set/yellow

The only downside is using this you have to manage your profiles when making videos. Also, enabling yellow highlighter. If you run two different type sof monitors you'll notice a different background hue on your mouse pointer

Alternatively I also usually enable "ctrl" to find my mouse pointer as well under "change mouse settings" in windows 7

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's the right direction. It does not highlight the cursor when clicking but when Ctrl is pressed. I think I'll forget that sometimes during the presentation.

Comment: NB: if I recall correctly, the *"Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key"* feature doesn't show the clicks in the screen recordings made with Windows 10 Screen recorder (WIN+ALT+R).